# I want to ask, how to throw a value from ajax to javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have code like this, ajax code is a method of retrieving data from php and the return I call it "RESPONSE". And the function $ (window). on ('load', function () {is a function in chat feature where I want to call the response feature contained in ajax to the "chat-msg" variable

```
    $(window).on('load', function() {

        var tags = [{
            type: "input",
            tag: "text",
            name: "name",
            "chat-msg": "Halo, Selamat datang di Sistem Pakar Diet? Nama kakak siapa?"  }, {
            type: "input",
            tag: "radio",
            name: "kegiatan",
            "chat-msg": "Senang bertemu denganmu, {{name}}! Kegiatan kakak sehari?",
            children: [{
                value: "olahraga",
                text: "Olahraga",
            }, {
                value: "kerja",
                text: "Kerja Kantoran",
            }, {
                value: "dirumah",
                text: "Dirumah",
            }]
        }, {
            type: "msg",
            "chat-msg": "Mimin juga suka {{kegiatan}}...",
            delay: 1250,
            callback: function() {
                var name = Chat.getData().name;
                Chat.addTags([{
                    type: "input",
                    tag: "radio",
                    name: "tricked",
                    "chat-msg": tampunganrespon,
                    children: [{
                        value: true,
                        text: "Ya"
                    }, {
                        value: false,
                        text: "Tidak"
                    }],
                    success: function(data) {
                        var msg = data.tricked == 'true' ? "";

                        Chat.addTags([{
                            type: "msg",
                            "chat-msg": msg,
                            delay: 2000
                        }]);
                    }
                }])
            }
        },


   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#display").click(function() {
            $.ajax({ 
             type: "GET",
                url: "datapertanyaan.php",
                dataType: "html",              
                success: function(response) {                
                    $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
                    alert(response);
                    return response;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: use a global variable, and assign response to that variable and then use it. but you need to make sure the ajax is completed before using the variable,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You means that Processing response outside of Ajax functions? You can package Ajax functions as a promise, In addition, you can encapsulate a function whose parameters contains a callback function so that you can deal with resposne with the callback